# Specifying One-hot Encoding on Combinations in Tidymodels

Tags: tidymodels

I have a data set with two columns Value and Pattern.  Value takes one of two values 0 or 1. The Pattern column is a three-character string.  The three-character string or Pattern is derived from 1 of 7 characters (X, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0, T) the characters can repeat so there are (7 x 7 x 7) = 343 possible Patterns.

I would like to use tidymodels to do some classification modeling and was planning on using one-hot encoding on the Pattern column, but have the following questions:

1. Is there a limit to the number of columns tidymodels can handle?
2. How do I handle a situation where not all of the patterns are represented in the dataset or that the test dataset has patterns no found in the training dataset.
3. Is one-hot encoding the best way to go here or does tidymodels offer an alternative better suited to my use case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. {tidymodels} doesn't inherently have a limit on the number of columns it can handle. The bottleneck you are more likely to see would be in the parsnip engines no being able to handle many columns. {tidymodels} would also complain if you are having so many levels in the column you are applying one-hot encoding to, that the resulting data.frame doesn't fit in your RAM.
2. As long as the `Pattern` column in the data.frame you are supplying to `recipe()` is a factor with all the possible levels then `step_dummy()` will make sure all the levels will be created in both the training data set and testing data set. Since you know all the possible values `Pattern` can take you should manually specify the levels in the training data set you are supplying to `recipe()`.

```r
library(tidymodels)

patterns <- c("X", "4", "3", "2", "1", "0", "T")
  
patern_constructor <- function(x) {
  paste(sample(patterns, size = 3, replace = FALSE, prob = seq_along(patterns)), 
      collapse = "")
}

all_patterns <- expand.grid(patterns, patterns, patterns) %>%
  tidyr::unite(pattern, sep = "") %>%
  pull(pattern)

data_patterns <- tibble(value = factor(sample(c(0,1), 10000, TRUE), c(0, 1)),
       pattern = factor(map_chr(seq_len(10000), patern_constructor), 
                        levels = all_patterns))

rec_patterns <- recipe(value ~ pattern, data = data_patterns) %>%
  step_dummy(pattern, one_hot = TRUE) %>%
  prep()

bake(rec_patterns, new_data = data_patterns)
#> # A tibble: 10,000 x 344
#>    value pattern_XXX pattern_X4XX pattern_X3XX pattern_X2XX pattern_X1XX
#>    <fct>       <dbl>        <dbl>        <dbl>        <dbl>        <dbl>
#>  1 1               0            0            0            0            0
#>  2 0               0            0            0            0            0
#>  3 1               0            0            0            0            0
#>  4 1               0            0            0            0            0
#>  5 1               0            0            0            0            0
#>  6 0               0            0            0            0            0
#>  7 0               0            0            0            0            0
#>  8 1               0            0            0            0            0
#>  9 1               0            0            0            0            0
#> 10 1               0            0            0            0            0
#> # … with 9,990 more rows, and 338 more variables: pattern_X0XX <dbl>,
#> #   pattern_TXX <dbl>, pattern_X4X <dbl>, pattern_X44X <dbl>,
#> #   pattern_X34X <dbl>, pattern_X24X <dbl>, pattern_X14X <dbl>, …

bake(rec_patterns, new_data = tibble(value = factor(1), 
                                     pattern = factor("000")))
#> # A tibble: 1 x 344
#>   value pattern_XXX pattern_X4XX pattern_X3XX pattern_X2XX pattern_X1XX
#>   <fct>       <dbl>        <dbl>        <dbl>        <dbl>        <dbl>
#> 1 1               0            0            0            0            0
#> # … with 338 more variables: pattern_X0XX <dbl>, pattern_TXX <dbl>,
#> #   pattern_X4X <dbl>, pattern_X44X <dbl>, pattern_X34X <dbl>,
#> #   pattern_X24X <dbl>, pattern_X14X <dbl>, pattern_X04X <dbl>, …
```

<sup>Created on 2021-03-04 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

3. This will depend on the distribution of patterns you see in your data. You may have to remove patterns that didn't show up in your training data with [`step_zv()`](https://recipes.tidymodels.org/reference/step_zv.html) if the model you are using can't handle zero variance predictors. If you are having a highly skewed distribution you could use [`step_other()`](https://recipes.tidymodels.org/reference/step_other.html) to collapse infrequent levels into one level. The [embed package](https://embed.tidymodels.org/index.html) also includes some steps to combine multiple levels into a lower space.

Comment: Thanks for the great response - much appreciated.  One question, in reviewing the patterns above it appears some have four characters ( X24X), and some have three (X4X).  Why don't they all have three characters?

Comment: This is happening because of the way `dummy_names()` created the names. (dummy_names() is the default function passed to `naming` in step_dummy()`) In this case, all the factor levels that start with a numeric have a leading X added